# Bad URL in swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurl

When I want to load a url it goes always into the `catch` block. How can i solve this? I think it's something with the escaped url.

If i set url in the `if` block it goes immediately to the `else` block.

```
let urls : String = Baseurl+"lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&APPID={"+apiKey+"}"
let escapedurl = urls.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: escapedurl!)!


        if let url = NSURL(string: escapedurl!) {
            do {
                let contents = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: nil)
                print(contents)
            } catch {
                // contents could not be loaded
                print("bad")
            }
        } else {
            // the URL was bad!
            print("bads")
        }
```

Comment: Show us the full URL.

Comment: Your `catch` block is there to let you find out more about the error. Right now you're ignoring all the information in the error object that's provided to you. See [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* for patterns you can use to inspect the error and find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLHostAllowedCharacterSet() returns the character set for characters allowed in a host URL subcomponent.

For example, in the URL http://www.example.com/index.html, the host component is www.example.com.

Try to change

```
let escapedurl = urls.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

into

```
let escapedurl = urls.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```